# Having issues with the scroll bar in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

So im trying to get my scroll bar to A only show up as needed and B show up only around my description text

Right now the scroll view is going from the top of the window to the bottom

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.DataWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="DataWindow" Height="300" Width="300">
<Grid>
    <Label x:Name="lblTitle" Content="Label" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="96,25,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="186"/>
    <Label x:Name="lblPublishDate" Content="Label" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="96,53,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="186"/>
    <Image x:Name="imgPic" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="81" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="81"/>
    <ScrollViewer>
        <TextBlock x:Name="tbDesc" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,96,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="167" Width="272" Text="TextBlock" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" />
    </ScrollViewer>

</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're pretty close, the problem appears to be an issue of layout. Because the controls are arranged in the grid without row and column definitions the scrollviewer is attempting to resize to the full size of the grid while the textblock is adhereing to its fixed size and margin. Try the following starting point and see if it helps:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="150"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0">
        <Label x:Name="lblTitle" Content="Label" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="186"/>
        <Label x:Name="lblPublishDate" Content="Label" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="186"/>
        <Image x:Name="imgPic" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="81" Width="81"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <TextBlock x:Name="tbDesc" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap"  Text="TextBlock"/>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Comment: After slightly modifying and formatting your answer i got exactly what i was looking for thank you ^_^

Answer (score 1):

A grid tries to let it's children take up all availble space.

Your ScrollViewer is one of the children, so it will fill all available space by default.

There are a number of ways around this.

- You could use a different panel type, one that doesn't try to stretch it's children to fill all available space. Based on what you're doing with excessively large margins, a `Canvas` might be suitable.

  I would suggest reading this for a quick understanding of WPF's available Layout Panels : [WPF Layouts -  A Visual Quick Start](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30904/WPF-Layouts-A-Visual-Quick-Start)
- Another alternative is to give your Grid some Row Definitions, and specify that the row containing the ScrollViewer should be of a fixed size, or should be sized so it fits whatever size the child object wants (Height="Auto")
- Or you could give your ScrollViewer a fixed height, and set it's `VerticalAlignment` property so it gets docked to either the top or bottom of the Grid.

Personally I would recommend the first option - reviewing WPF's layout system and determining a more approrpiate panel type for your layout. And if the most appropriate panel type *is* a Grid, then I would highly recommend using the RowDefinitions and ColumnDefinitions to give your Grid some structure, rather than trying to use excessively large Margins to position your controls.